# ANDROID STUDIO: Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings

Tags: android-studio

aparece o seguinte alerta quando tento rodar um emulador no Android Studio:

```
Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.
/dev/kvm is not found.

Enable VT-x in your BIOS security settings, ensure that your Linux distro has working KVM module.
```

Mas o VT já está ativado, então procure aqui no stack overflow e vi que tinha que desativar o Hyper-V, fiz isso e continua sem funcionar, oque posso fazer?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS: uso windows 7, 64 bits

Comment: Qual seu processador?

Comment: é um i3, acha que é por causa disso?

Comment: Não é não, seria se fosse amd, tenta desinstalar o HAXM e instalar novamente.